# will_paginate gem rendering each entry 4 times rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, will-paginate

I am using will_paginate with rails 4 and have the following code in my users controller:

```
def index
  @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => 10)
end
```

and in my view:

```
<% provide(:title, 'All users') %>
<h1>All Users</h1>

<%= will_paginate %>

<ul class="users">
  <% @users.each do |user| %>
     <%= render @users %>
  <% end %>
</ul>

<%= will_paginate %>
```

This renders all the users however there are 40 per page, not 10. Each page has the correct users but 4 times. For example it renders users 1 .. 10 then 1 .. 10 again and so on. There are currently 101 users and if I set the per page limit to 1 it renders 101 pages with one user on each page as it should however any limit > 1 and it breaks.

Any insight on how to fix it so only 10 users appear on each page would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure `<%= render @users %>` is correct? shouldn't that be `<%= render user %>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found your mistake. You need to render @users once. Hope it works on your side. :)

```
<ul class="users">
   <%= render @users %>
</ul>
```

also you need to render pagination with following code

```
<%= will_paginate @users %>
```

Comment: Yes of course. I need to go to sleep! I don't know how I didn't catch that!? It seems I was in the middle of refactoring and forgot the finish. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference the block variable `user` within the render call, not `@users`

```
<ul class="users">
  <% @users.each do |user| %>
     <%= render user %>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```